# Handling an exception thrown by a server running a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

I am creating a tool in C# windows form at work which quickly checks the status of an order placed in our company's internal ordering website.  I am attempting to handle a formatting exception thrown by the web request when it attempts to open a new IE window.

My tool adds the 8 digit user input and adds this to a URL to get the user the specific order and opens a new IE window to show it.

```
private void scRequestBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    try
    {
        var scUrl = "http://iwha.mycompany.com/servicesdashboard/InstanceInfoRedirect.aspx?instance_id=";
        var scInput = scUrl += scTextBox.Text;
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", scInput);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your entry is not valid.  Please verify the ID number");
    }
}
```

If information other than the 8 digit number is entered (for example if the user types in a string as opposed to integers) I get an IE window with a server error.  It has a stacktrace as follows:

> `[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>      Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDecimal(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +203
>      Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String Value) +73`
>
> `[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "gsdfgsdfgsfg" to type 'Long' is not valid.]
>      Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String Value) +328
>      ServiceDashboard_41.InstanceInfoRedirect.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +86
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627`

I feel that the exception thrown by an internal server hosting the ordering site throws a different type of exception than a typical one you would see.  I have read that a "Soap" exception might be what this is called however I do not truly understand how to handle this.

My question is how would you handle an exception which is thrown by something not within to your program?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Sanitize the user input to make sure it conforms to what they should be entering.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the server / webpage, you would have to check the HTTP return code. It's the only way you can check if an error occurred.

From what I can see in your code you only open IE with an input on your side. You could also try to format the input for the server (I wants a long so you could check the input is numeric)

Encasing the process start in a try catch statement will allow you to handle the error.